# Show Oracle Apex Select List by Default

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a tabular form in which I need to generate a dynamic amount of select lists based on the number of values in COL1 that are relevant to the query.

```
APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST_FROM_QUERY_XL(5, COL1, 'query...',p_show_null=>'NO') "COL1"
```

This works fine when the query returns at least one row. It creates *x* amount of select lists where *x* is the number of rows returned by the query. However, when no rows are returned, no select lists are created. How can I make it generate one select list when the query returns no results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
select ...,
       APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST_FROM_QUERY_XL(5, COL1, 'query...',p_show_null=>'NO') "COL1"
  from ...
 where ...
union all
select ...,
       APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST_FROM_QUERY_XL(5, 'xxx', 'query...',p_show_null=>'NO') "COL1"
  from dual
 where not exists (select null from <first query>)
```